# Roblox image transparency does not change

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a system where if the player has a specific item in their file(a file added to the player) an Gui image label background transparency is changed to tell the user if he has clamed the item or not. I tried it and nothing happened, was the same transparency as I left it.

here is my code:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local catscollected = player:WaitForChild("catsCollected")

if catscollected:FindFirstChild("sleeping cat") then
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
else
    script.Parent.Transparency = 0.25
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is only running once, and that is when the player joins. If you want it to keep checking, put it in a loop:

```lua
while true do
  if catscollected:FindFirstChild("sleeping cat") then
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
  else
    script.Parent.Transparency = 0.25
  end
  wait()
end
```

Note that this loop will hold the script, so anything after the loop won’t run. To fix that, I recommend you put this in its own script (if it isn’t already).

Comment: Your loop needs to yield with a `wait()`, otherwise your loop will time out and stop running.

Comment: Thank you @Kaylaa. I’ve gone ahead and fixed the code. It’s been a while since I did any Lua or Roblox programming, so my skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: @Fastnlight thank you for your help, sorry for asking such a stupid question

Comment: @catmanXVZ, this is not a dumb question. You tried something and it didn't work, that's just part of learning. But if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: @kylaaa, okay I'll put that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The image transparency change is NOT working at all because you're using the `Transparency` property. The properties available for your image label would be `BackgroundTransparency` (which changes background transparency) and `ImageTransparency` (which changes the image transparency).